# Chrome (Webkit) WebSQL Database maximum file size?

Tags: database, sqlite, html, google-chrome, webkit

I'm trying to find some information on the maximum size a WebSQL (SQLite) database can be on Google Chrome. I've read conflicting information such as max size is 5MB and the User is prompted when DB reaches 10, 50, 100MB etc.

I've tried creating DB's of various sizes and they open fine at 500MB and 5,000MB, however I've yet to try adding data up to these large sizes.

Does anyone have any first hand experience with large WebSQL DB's or can point me at relevant information?

Answer (score 7):

Here's a link to the most solid article on the subject I've found so far:http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/. Helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure about the max size for a database on a normal webpage, but if you need a lot of storage, you can make an extension that requests the "unlimitedStorage" permission. See http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to create a database over the size of the default database size, 5MB. The popup is shown the image below, asking whether you want to grant the database permission to scale up to the next size of database — 5MB++ to onwards. In short, you can have unlimited size but if user want.

[image]