# Buffering and using large amounts of data in a web browser

Tags: javascript, php, json, html

I am currently building a web app which will take JSON formatted data containing positional information on things, and play it like a video.

The data can be considerably large (from 25MB up to 400MB). If I were building this app using something else I'd stream the replay from disk, but as far as I know I'm prevented from doing this (in a cross-platform way) in the browser.

Currently I'm parsing this data as I get it (it downloads in chunks) into JSON objects and storing in an array, but this is causing issues with HUGE memory usage and can crash the browser in some cases.

I'm looking for a way to 'buffer' this data on the client and use it as it is needed, the only requirements being it works on both the latest stable Firefox version and the latest stable Chrome version, both desktop.

Is there a way?

Comment: HTML5's local storage perhaps

Comment: Both Firefox and Chrome supports streaming, and they also both support ASM.js if you can compile it with that somehow

Comment: Depending on what kind of data you have (indexable or not?) there is always [webSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480879/chrome-webkit-websql-database-maximum-file-size).  Another solution could be to make a chrome-extension / firefox-addon, which have no disk size restrictions.

Comment: you want streaming data. Only hold in memory what you need, buffer enough to get you through the next interval, and then ask for more. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/ has some good info.